# Cross Compiling for Arm armv5tejl

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, arm

I am trying to cross compile a simple hello world program for a linux system.

I have the following information:

```
uname -a
Linux (none) 2.6.32.28 #130 PREEMPT Mon Feb 18 13:54:18 CST 2013 armv5tejl GNU/Linux

cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 421.06 
Features        : swp half fastmult edsp java
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : KeyASIC Ka2000 EVM
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

I would like to know how to cross compile for this system. I have tried the following:

- arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c -march=armv5 -o helloworld
- arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -o helloworld

But when I try and run the executable I get the error message "command not found".
I am probably not compiling it correctly but I don't know what compile options to use given the information I have.

(I know the helloworld.c is all working).

```
ls -l helloworld
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        0             8428 Jan  1 00:00 helloworld

which helloworld
which: applet not found
```

I put busybox-armv5l on

```
busybox which helloworld
(no output)
```

ldd is also not on the system I am trying to compile for (its the transcend WifiSD card).

```
ls -ln /lib/libc*
-rwxrwxrwx    1 0        0           244279 Jan 19  2012 /lib/libc.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx    1 0        0            13043 Jan 19  2012 /lib/libcrypt.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        0          1251776 Jan  1 00:00 /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

I tried to run /lib/libc.so.0 to get version information and I got a segmentation fault. It seems compiling with -static fixed the issue. So I guess it was an issue with the libc library. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What's the output of the following commands inside the target system inside the directory where you copied helloworld?  
  
    ls -l helloworld;  
  
    which helloworld;  
  
    ldd helloworld;

Comment: Balau, I have updated the question with the outputs. (Couldn't add them to this comment.)

Comment: I hope you're trying to run it with './helloworld' and if so, try to compile it with '-static' flag. Warning though, binary will be significantly bigger.

Comment: Please print the output of `ls -l /lib/libc*.so /lib/libc.*`.  This shows the *libc* of the target.  Your `gcc` version is *glibc/eglibc*.  As well, the kernel may use **OABI**.  You can use some options with `ld` to turn on debug, like `ldd`.  `export LD_DEBUG=all` before attempting to run for example.

Comment: Thank you for the help, compiling with the static flag fixed the issue. I added results in the above post, it seems there is something wrong with libc. I would accept as an answer but it doesn't seem to have the option on a comment. I didn't try using export LD_DEBUG=all but ldd doesn't exist within PATH directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use -static flag to include c libraries in the binary. Thanks to auselen.